# Make peer failed in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using go version 1.6 on Ubuntu system. When i tried to create peer i am getting following error.
$ make peer

```
.build/bin/peer
CGO_CFLAGS=" " GOBIN=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/.build/bin go install -tags "experimental" -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.Version=1.2.0 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.CommitSHA=9acd9cd -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseVersion=0.4.8 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerLabel=org.hyperledger.fabric -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.DockerNamespace=hyperledger -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerNamespace=hyperledger -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.Experimental=true" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
vendor/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient/client_unix.go:10:2: cannot find package "context" in any of:
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/context (vendor tree)
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/context (from $GOROOT)
    /opt/gopath/src/context (from $GOPATH)
bccsp/factory/pluginfactory.go:12:2: cannot find package "plugin" in any of:
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/plugin (vendor tree)
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/plugin (from $GOROOT)
    /opt/gopath/src/plugin (from $GOPATH)
Makefile:256: recipe for target '.build/bin/peer' failed
make: *** [.build/bin/peer] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use golang 1.10 and in general see the [prerequisites](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/prereqs.html) page.